Normalizing Flow with Highly Negative NLL Loss
I am following the Zuko "Train From Data" tutorial to train a Neural Spline Flow. My goal is to approximate a distribution over functions.
Therefore, each of my function samples are actually 20 spline coefficients. If I can learn the distribution over these coefficients, then I approximate the function distribution. Overall I am using 100K samples to fit the flow. Each sample has 20 dimensions.
It's currently not working, and flow samples do not look like the functions in my data. Also, my NLL loss is negative, often around -30. This means that on average, the density of my samples is on the order of exp(30)?!
This seems like overfitting to my data, but my train/test losses are nearly equal. And still my sampled functions are garbage.
Here is the code for my training loop:
def train(samples):

    train_ratio = 25.0/26.0
    total_samples = samples.size(0)
    indices = torch.randperm(total_samples)

    train_size = int(train_ratio * total_samples)
    train_indices = indices[:train_size]
    test_indices = indices[train_size:]

    train_samples, test_samples = samples[train_indices], samples[test_indices]

    num_features = samples.shape[1]
    flow = zuko.flows.NSF(features=num_features, transforms=5, hidden_features=(64, 128, 256))
    # flow = zuko.flows.MAF(features=num_features, transforms=32)

    num_epochs = 10000
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(flow.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

    ms = [int(0.2*num_epochs), int(0.7*num_epochs), int(0.9*num_epochs)]
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=ms, gamma=0.1)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_loss = -flow().log_prob(train_samples).mean()
        train_loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        scheduler.step()

        with torch.no_grad():
            test_loss = -flow().log_prob(test_samples).mean()

        lr = optimizer.param_groups[-1]['lr']
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], LR: {lr:.6f}, Train: {train_loss.item():.8f}, Test: {test_loss.item():.8f}')

    return flow

This results in train and test losses of about -45 and -44 respectively after 400 epochs, which seems ridiculous to me.

how well does it work on 2 spline coefs? On a single spline coef? Do you have any code you can share? Fitting neural flows is really hard, so the more info/code you can share with us the better.

I have not tried it yet for one or two spline coefficients, but I have edited my post to include my training loop code.
I guess I am just so confused that both the train and test loss could be so low. I just can't believe that my distribution would be that spiked...
